# how to parse unstructured uk address into address components in Python?

Tags: python

I found this library which parse unstructured US address into address components in python - https://usaddress.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Is there a similar library for UK address ?

```
Guildford Cathedral Enterprises Limited The Cathedral Church Of The Holy Spirit, Stag Hill The Chase GU2 7UP
```

Comment: I need this to - find anything good?

Answer (score 0):

I have a fairly horrible solution for you.

```py
    address_types = {
        "address_line_1": ["street_number", "route", "subpremise", "street_address"],
        "address_line_2": ["neighborhood", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality_level_2",
                           "sublocality_level_3", "sublocality_level_4", "sublocality_level_5"],
        "town": ["locality", "postal_town"],
        "county": ["administrative_area_level_2", "administrative_area_level_3"],
        "postcode": ["postal_code"]
    }
```

These fields that googles geolocation API return in the raw address components roughly relate to the key of the dictionary.

ifs its a business you can use the places search and lookup the place ID and then search the address

```py
results  = gmaps.find_place(f"{company} + {raw_add}", "textquery",
                                   fields=['name', 'place_id', "types", "formatted_address"])

google_address = results["candidates"][0]["formatted_address"]
```

This only give you the raw_address (i.e a string) but you've got the place ID , and company name, which you can use fuzzywuzzy to match to a set threshold to the name and raw_address for confirmation you have the correct place.

or also add a lookup for type

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types

check table 1.

Once you've confirmed a match you can do this

`place = gmaps.place(place_id, fields=["address_component"])`

Yeah its 2 api calls, boo hoo.

`place["result"][0]["address_components"]` is built like this :

```json
[
  {"name": "1 foo bar lane" , "short_name", "1 foo bar ln", "types":  [street_address,....]},
  {"name": "foo barton" , "short_name", "foo barton", "types": ["postal_town"]},
  {"name": "FO0 8AR" , "short_name", "FO0 8AR", "types": ["postal_code"]},
]
```

Then you can again attempt to match by what ever means you see fit.

You can also give https://deepparse.org/ a go, but I found the results sub par against my dataset, which is the devil (user input).

Company
Address line 1
address line 2
Town
County

I nearly always end up just splitting by the "," and using a regex to confirm the postcode. First one index goes to company, last to postcode, regex match the postcode and then depending on the amount of available elements left just allocate to some fields:

```
split_add = raw_address.split(",") 
company = split_add[0]
postcode = split_add[-1]

left_overs = len(split_add[1:-1])

if left_overs == 3:
   address_line_2 = split_add[1]
   town = split_add[2]
   county = split_add[3]
elif left_overs == 2:
   town = split_add[1]
   county = split_add[2]
end if
```

if you really have to have all fields complete.

I do a `dirty_phil` named after a guy I once knew.

```
def dirty_phil(add_dict):

    """
    Fills the blank fields with duplicate data from the other fields.

    Returns:

    """
    fields_order = ["address_line_1", "address_line_2", "town", "county"]
    last_val = ""

    values = [v for k, v in add_dict.items() if v.strip() and k in fields_order]
    new_dict = OrderedDict({})
    for i, field in enumerate(fields_order):
        try:
            new_dict[field] = values[i]
        except IndexError:
            new_dict[field] = ""

    for field in fields_order:
        if not add_dict[field] and last_val:
            new_dict[field] = last_val
        else:
            new_dict[field] = add_dict[field]
        last_val = new_dict[field]
```